# Probability Theory - Independent Uniform Variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Suppose $X, Y$ are independent uniform(0,1) random variables. For some arbitrary $t$, I want to find $P(X/Y \le t)$. I am trying to draw a picture to figure this out, but I don't think I am accomplishing too much. Could I have some direction on how to do this?

For clarity, $t$ is arbitrary. I have no information on what it is.

Comment: Draw a unit square and a line $y=\frac{1}{t} x$ and compare the areas. Treat $t <0$, $0 \lt t \lt 1$ and $1 \lt t$ as separate cases

Comment: @324 answer performed with graphic and details . Hope this help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all note that $T=\frac{X}{Y} \in(0;+\infty)$

The result is the following

$$\mathbb{P}[T\leq t]=\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $t<0$ } \\
\frac{t}{2}, & \text{if $0\leq t<1$}\\
1-\frac{1}{2t}, & \text{if $t\geq 1$}\\
\end{cases}$$

To understand this result take a look at the following drawing

[image]

$$\mathbb{P}\Bigg[\frac{X}{Y} \leq t\Bigg]=\mathbb{P}\Bigg[Y > \frac{X}{t}\Bigg]$$

thus the probability you are looking for is the purple area. When $t<1$ it is easy to calculate 1 minus white triangle's area